# Error when doing npm install [Angular 2]

Tags: node.js, angular

Hello all I am getting the following error when doing `npm install` I have reinstalled my nodejs also but that is not working, I am not behind the firewall

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\ch
okidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"
})
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Satish Kumar\\Ap
pData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Satish Kumar\Desktop\angular2-course-master\node_modules\
.staging\invert-kv-e1d023cb\package.json.143624776
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Satish Kumar\De
sktop\angular2-course-master\node_modules\.staging\invert-kv-e1d023cb\package.js
on.143624776' -> 'C:\Users\Satish Kumar\Desktop\angular2-course-master\node_modu
les\.staging\invert-kv-e1d023cb\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Satish Kumar
\Desktop\angular2-course-master\node_modules\.staging\invert-kv-e1d023cb\package
.json.143624776' -> 'C:\Users\Satish Kumar\Desktop\angular2-course-master\node_m
odules\.staging\invert-kv-e1d023cb\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Satish Kumar\\Desktop\\angular2-course-master\\node
_modules\\.staging\\invert-kv-e1d023cb\\package.json.143624776',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\\Users\\Satish Kumar\\Desktop\\angular2-course-master\\node
_modules\\.staging\\invert-kv-e1d023cb\\package.json',
npm ERR!   parent: 'angular2-quickstart' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Satish Kumar\Desktop\angular2-course-master\npm-debug.log
```

Somehow I fixed the above error by running the npm install in admin mode
but, now when doing npm start I am getting the error listed below please help

```
  C:\Users\Satish Kumar\Desktop\angular2-course-master>npm start

> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Satish Kumar\Desktop\angular2-course-
master
> tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"

app/posts/posts.component.ts(6,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'underscore
'.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Satish Kumar\\Ap
pData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "
npm run lite" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrent
ly "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart p
ackage,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Satish Kumar\Desktop\angular2-course-master\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: for npm permission problems [check here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)

Comment: `app/posts/posts.component.ts(6,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'underscore
'.` maybe missing dependencies in package.json

Comment: try the last version of node (>= 7.4)

Comment: seems windows. right click on `gitshell` or `cmd` . click on `Run as Administrator` and proceed with installation.